# How to retrieve current moment default time zone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

If I set default moment time zone with `moment.tz.setDefault()`, is there a way to later retrieve the current default time zone?

Example:

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Tokyo');

console.log(moment.tz.getDefault()); // TypeError: moment.tz.getDefault is not a function
console.log(moment.tz.default);      // undefined
console.log(moment.tz.guess());      // America/New_York (my local timezone)
console.log(moment.tz.guess(true));  // America/New_York

// => I want something that will return "Asia/Tokyo"
```

This is different from the suggested duplicate because I don't want the *browser's* time zone, I specifically want to know what (if anything) `moment.tz.setDefault()` was set to.

Comment: Hello,
Can't find anything online that allows you to do that but since you are pre-setting it in the setDefault wouldn't you be able to use some sort of if statement and and then do what you want to do? momentjs is also not maintained aaik, so I'd suggest dayjs, datefns or luxon

Comment: @ImDarkk i'm dealing with a big legacy codebase, the call to setDefault() might happen somewhere out of my control

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the client's time zone (and offset) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-time-zone-and-offset-in-javascript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey my question shows what `.guess()` does (which is not what I need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by `moment.defaultZone.name`:

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Tokyo');

console.log(moment.defaultZone.name)
```

Output:

```
Asia/Tokyo
```

---

**Update after @Kip comment**

- If no default time zone is set, `moment.defaultZone` is undefined, so use `moment.defaultZone?.name` to be safe.
- Other approach which uses documented functionality is `moment().format('ZZ')` which returns `"+0900"` in Tokyo time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `tz.guess()` guesses the browser (or server, in node.js) time zone. The question is about retrieving the current moment default time zone, which `tz.guess()` ignores (or maybe it eventually falls back to it if it fails to come up with a guess?)

Comment: Yeah, I got that from your other comment. I'm usually very cautious about using undocumented properties in production code, but considering moment is no longer maintained, I guess you don't have to worry about that...

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. A few things to note- if no default time zone is set, `moment.defaultZone` is undefined, so I need to do `moment.defaultZone?.name` to be safe. Also, one other approach I found which uses documented functionality is `moment().format('ZZ')` which returns `"+0900"` in Tokyo time. That was enough for my use case (I really just wanted to know if it was set to anything other than UTC).

Comment: Thanks for the additions @Kip! I added it to the answer